# Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I keep getting the following error:

- TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no
  timezones

At this line

```
df['days_in_Month'].loc[df['Month'] == min_date_Month] = (df['Month_end'] - \
                                                          pd.to_datetime(min_date,format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

My df['TransactionDate'] is a column with the following format 2019-08-23T00:00:00.000Z. I am programming on Python3.3.7.

```
df['Month'] = df['TransactionDate'].apply(lambda x : str(x)[:7])
df['Month_begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format="%Y-%m") + MonthBegin(0)
df['Month_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format="%Y-%m") + MonthEnd(1)

df['days_in_Month'] = (df['Month_end'] - df['Month_begin'])#.days()
print(df.columns)
print(df)

min_date = df['TransactionDate'].min()
min_date_Month = min_date[:7]

df['days_in_Month'].loc[df['Month'] == min_date_Month] = (df['Month_end'] - \
                                                          pd.to_datetime(min_date,format="%Y-%m-%d"))
df['Month_begin'].loc[df['Month'] == min_date_Month] = pd.to_datetime(min_date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a piece of your offending instruction:

```
pd.to_datetime(min_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

you will get:

```
Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

It indicates that *format="%Y-%m-%d"* does not prevent this function
from parsing the **whole** input string, so the result is **with**
a time zone.

To parse **only** the date part, run:

```
pd.to_datetime(min_date[:10])
```

(even without *format*) and you will get:

```
Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00')
```

**without** the time zone.

But the whole your instruction is weird.
When you run the **left hand side** alone:

```
df['days_in_Month'].loc[df['Month'] == min_date_Month]
```

you will get:

```
0   29 days
Name: days_in_Month, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

But when you run the **right hand side** alone:

```
df['Month_end'] - pd.to_datetime(min_date[:10])
```

you will get:

```
0    29 days
1    60 days
2    91 days
3   120 days
Name: Month_end, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So you attempt to save the **whole column** under a **single cell**.

Maybe this instruction should be:

```
df['days_in_Month'] =  df['Month_end'] - pd.to_datetime(min_date[:10])
```

instead?

And yet another remark: Your *days_in_Month* column is actually of
*timedelta64* type, not the number of days.

To have the number of days in each month (as an **integer**), you should run:

```
df['days_in_Month'] = (df['Month_end'] - df['Month_begin']).dt.days + 1
```

Note that e.g. the difference between *2019-11-01* and *2019-11-30*
is **29** days, whereas November has **30** days.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the Z in your datetimestring causes the datetime to be interpretted as utc timezone

but your Month_end key does not have any timezone info attached to it, so it does not have a timezone associated with it

pandas does not know how to interact with these two different things, so you need to either remove the timezone from the datetime string, or better make your other datetimes timezone aware to utc.

pandas makes this relatively easy

```
Month_end = pandas.to_datetime(month_end_strings,utc=True)
```